# Telegraf loading snmp plugin, but not appearing on influxdb2

Tags: snmp, telegraf, influxdb-2

maybe someone here can point me to the correct direction. I have setup telegraf and influxdb2. My goal is to enable snmp plugin and graph it with grafana.

I enabled snmp plugin on telegraf.conf and nodes configs on telegraf.d folder. The configs look good and telegraf is writing to the bucket. My issue is when I go to influxdb to query I don’t see snmp plugin listed there. Does anybody know how to fix this?

I restarted telegraf, influxdb and nothing change.